# Google Cloud Speech to Text Accuracy Issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

i am trying to convert an audio file to a transcript using google cloud speech to text.

- [the python code](https://github.com/mohannksr/Speeck_to_Text/blob/master/Google_Longaudio_API_speaker_diarization_Test.ipynb)
- [Audio file](https://github.com/mohannksr/Speeck_to_Text/blob/master/InboundSampleRecording.wav) used for conversion
- [Transcript](https://github.com/mohannksr/Speeck_to_Text/blob/master/InboundSampleRecording.txt)

i am not getting the better accuracy when i check the transcript. How to improve it?

i am new to this topic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a minimal reproducible example, which can be tested by others

Answer (score 0):

Use the enhanced models. That will increase accuracy. Since you are transcribing a conversation, use the 'phone' model. I suggest you try the 'video' model as well.

Comment: i tried "phone_model".it works fine.Thanks for your suggestion.